# How use liferay validator with js submit?

Tags: javascript, html, liferay, liferay-6

I try to use Liferay validator with javascript on Liferay 6.2.

Have a problem is my button must using submit form with a button onlick, but when submit this way Liferay form validator no trigger prevent submit. It just triggers when I using a button type submit.

Here mycode example:

```
 <portlet:actionURL name="updateURL" var="submitURL"/>

<aui:form name="fm2" id="fm2" action="<%=submitURL %>" method="post">
    <aui:input name="userName" value='' label="User Name"></aui:input>
    <aui:input name="password" value='' label="Password"></aui:input>

    <aui:button type="button" name="logIn" id="logIn" value="Login" />
</aui:form>
<aui:script>
AUI().use('aui-base','liferay-form','aui-form-validator',function(A){

    A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>logIn").on("click",function(){
        submitForm(document.<portlet:namespace />fm2);
    });

    Liferay.Form.register(
        {
            id: '<portlet:namespace/>fm2',
            fieldRules: [
                            {
                                body: '',
                                custom: false,
                                errorMessage: '',
                                fieldName: '<portlet:namespace/>password',
                                validatorName: 'required'
                            },

                            {
                                body: '',
                                custom: false,
                                errorMessage: '',
                                fieldName: '<portlet:namespace/>userName',
                                validatorName: 'required'
                            }
                ]

        });
    });
</aui:script>
```

What i can do ?

How to liferay can prevent event submit with tag, but does not with js?

Here is AUIFormValidator-portlet to demo.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B27gY2oYFX7QTTFFdXc3TnZ4d1k

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing,

```
<aui:form name="fm2" id="fm2" action="javascript:void(0)" method="post">
```

It will prevent your submit event and fire the aui form validation.

Now in onClick function you can assign your submit url to form action like below.

```
 $("#<portlet:namespace/>logIn").on("click",function(){
    var url = '${submitURL}';
    $('#<portlet:namespace />fm2').attr('action', url);
    $('#<portlet:namespace />fm2').trigger("submit");
 });
```